# Unset/Remove a yum repo option with yum-config-manager

Tags: yum, rhel7

It's RHEL 7. I can set an option like this:

`yum-config-manager --setopt=developer_repo.proxy=http://proxy.example.com:80/ --save`

But how do I unset/remove the option using yum-config-manager if it is no longer needed?

Kind regards,
Dietmar